# How to prove that function ${f(x) = x \oplus T}$ is injective or surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have set `T` of natural pair values (2, 4, 6, etc.)

The function is f(x) = P(N) -> P(N)

defined as ${f(x) = x \oplus T}$

Question is - is this function injective or surjective?

As far as I see this function is injective because of f(a) = f(b) -> a = b (but I am not sure it is right)

About surjective

```
f(x) = y
```

means ${y = x \oplus T}$, but how to get `x` from this expression?

I know that XOR is

[image]

But anyway how it can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking relates to very profound results regarding very naturally occurring structures in what is known as **lattice theory**. Let us formulate things more generally:

> **Theorem.** Consider an arbitrary set $A$ and the binary operation of symmetric difference
>   $\oplus: \mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(A) \to \mathscr{P}(A), X \oplus Y=(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus X)$. Then $(\mathscr{P}(A), \oplus)$ is **a commutative group.**

*Proof:*

1. **The associativity** of $\oplus$ is the most tedious aspect to verify here and it can be done by patient calculation; for arbitrary $X, Y, Z \subseteq A$ you should obtain in the end that:
   $$(X \oplus Y)\oplus Z=X \oplus (Y \oplus Z)=(X \setminus (Y \cup Z)) \cup (Y \setminus (Z \cup X)) \cup (Z \setminus (X \cup Y)) \cup (X \cap Y \cap Z)$$
2. $\varnothing$ is obviously **the neutral element** with respect to this operation, since 
   $$X \setminus \varnothing=X, \varnothing \setminus X= \varnothing$$
3. The existence of symmetrizable elements is based on a remarkable observation, namely that **every element is its own symmetric** with respect to this operation; indeed, it is obvious that $X\oplus X=\varnothing$.
4. Commutativity is easily observed to hold, since **binary union is commutative** (in other words $M \cup N=N \cup M$ for any sets $M, N$). $\Box$

Thus, your problem can be now treated in the following general setting:

> Assume $(G, \cdot)$ is an arbitrary group (with binary operation written in multiplicative notation) and for every $t \in G$ consider the map $\gamma_t: G \to G, \gamma_t(x)=tx$, the so-called **left-translation given by** $t$. Then $\gamma_t$ is **a permutation of** $G$ (i.e. bijection from $G$ to itself), **with inverse given by** $\gamma_{t^{-1}}$.

In your particular case, the map $f$ as you denote it **is its own inverse (what one calls an involution)**.